# Is there a way to create multiple measures at once in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am new to power bi and I have a table that has sales by state by month and I need to calculate the broker fee for each month.

I know how to create a new column/measure that will give me the amount paid in fees in a particular month. Is there a way to create 12 measures/columns  at once?

[image: Sample Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the query editor and use "Unpivot Columns" function to create a new table with multiple measure values in a new column.

First use the `duplicate` function to backup your table.
And then choose month columns and click on `"Unpivot Columns"` to merge them.

Comment: Thank you for this! You saved me much work and aggravation